# Gulp task failed with error: MSBuild failed with code 1! in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, gulp, visual-studio-2019, sitecore

I know there are few questions on SO but they are either unanswered or solutions were not helpful for me.

This gulp task executes successfully on other machine with `Visual Studio 2017` but not on `Visual Studio 2019`.

When I run "Build-Solution" task, it fails with below error

> [11:33:58] Starting 'Build-Solution'...
>
> MSBUILD : error MSB1001:
>
> Unknown switch. Switch: /restore For switch syntax, type "MSBuild
>
> /help" [11:33:59] MSBuild failed with code 1! [11:33:59]
>
> 'Build-Solution' errored after 1.04 s [11:33:59] Error: MSBuild failed
> with code 1!
>
> ```
> at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\MyProj\node_modules\gulp-msbuild\lib\msbuild-runner.js:66:25)
>
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
>
> at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:506:15)
>
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
>
> at Process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:126:14) Process terminated with code 1.
> ```

Comment: It seems the `Unknown switch. Switch: /restore` is the key information, the issue should be related to the `/restore`. I don’t see the full command/task, but was this Switch written correctly and matched the format/rule? Maybe the `/restore` should be replaced by `-restore`/`-r`? ([MSBuild CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019#:~:text=--,restore,--r))

Comment: @Tianyu this works in VS2017 so I believe it is written correctly. Something has to do with VS2019?

Comment: Perhaps there are some adjustments for VS 2019, including some new strict rules. Not very familiar with Gulp task, but the MSBuild doc indeed showed to use –restore syntax.

Answer (score 0):

So it depends on what build script you are using. The default gulp script used with Sitecore Habitat is using this gulp module :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-msbuild

And, you are using this module to build with task like this one

```
gulp.task("default", function() {
return gulp.src("./project.sln")
    .pipe(msbuild({
        targets: ['Clean', 'Build'],
        toolsVersion: 3.5
        })
    );
```

});

If you are using this one, I guess you are trying to use an msbuild switch in your task like :

```
gulp.task("default", function() {
return gulp.src("./project.sln")
    .pipe(msbuild({
        ...,
        restore:true
        ...
        })
    );
```

});

Because yes, Msbuild offer such switch, that you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019), but the [gulp-msbuild](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-msbuild) plugin is trying to use vs2017 by default if I am not wrong.
From [msbuild-finder.js](https://github.com/fluffynuts/gulp-msbuild/blob/master/lib/msbuild-finder.js) you can see that it is looking for msbuild tool in vs2017 directory :

```
  function detectMsBuild15Dir(pathRoot) {

  const vs2017Path = path.join(pathRoot, "Microsoft Visual Studio", "2017");
  const possibleFolders = [ "BuildTools", "Enterprise", "Professional", "Community" ];

  for (let index = 0; index < possibleFolders.length; index++) {
    try {
      const folderPath = path.join(vs2017Path, possibleFolders[index]);
      fs.statSync(folderPath);
      return folderPath;
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
}
```

But, if you specify the version path, you should be good (from [msbuild-command-builder.js](https://github.com/fluffynuts/gulp-msbuild/blob/master/lib/msbuild-command-builder.js)) :

```
  if (!options.msbuildPath) {
    const msbuildFinder = require("./msbuild-finder");
    options.msbuildPath = msbuildFinder.find(options);
  }
```

With Visual Studio 2019 installed you should use buildToolsVersion 15.0 I believe. See [this thread](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/issues/467);

On an other note, you may want to use [msbuild plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msbuild) instead. I have also [an article](https://razmo.ca/sitecore-build-script-with-gulp-js-4/) that cover switch from gulp3.9 to gulp4 that has some msbuild exemple within. You may find it relevant